# How to print in HEX format the MSBs bits when they're equal to 0

Tags: c, hex, printf

I need to print variables using `HEX` format.
The problem is when my variables are little the MSBs equal 0 so they are not printed.

```
ex: uint16_t var = 10; // (0x000A)h
```

-> I need to print `"000A"` but no matter what I do it always prints just `'A'`

How could I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a leading `0` to the width specifier in order to force `printf` to add leading zeros (at least, you can in C and C++ - not *entirely* sure about other languages that use the function).

For example, in C, the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t a = 10; // 0xA
    printf("%04X\n", a);
    //        ^ width specifier: display as 4 digits
    //       ^ this signals to add leading zeros to pad to at least "n" digits
    return 0;
}
```

will display:

```
000A
```